# Joomla 3 Protostar template disappeared

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I was downloading different templates and trying them out and now have noticed that the default Protostar template is missing from the list of templates in the admin app.  How do I get it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy the template folder from the [Joomla 3.4 full package](http://www.joomla.org/download.html).

Simply download the file, unzip everything (or only the `templates\protostar\` folder) to your Joomla folder. Then use the discover function (**Extensions** -> **Extension Manager** -> Discover) to discover and install the Protostar template again.

[image: Discover extensions in Joomla]

Comment: Great idea.  I had never thought of that.